# How do I visually identify parallel lines in Desargues' finite geometry?

Tags: geometry

I saw two different possible models of Desargues' finite geometry in Geogebra. The first one is this,

[image]

and the second one is this,
[image]

In the first image, it is obvious to me to see parallel lines. However, the second image confuses me. Can someone help me understand how to identify parallel lines in this model, for example in the second image, $\overleftrightarrow{AP}$?

Comment: These are not "models of Desargues' finite geometry". They are illustrations of [Desargues' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues's_theorem). The first illustrates a case where there are parallel lines. The second illustrates a case where none of the lines are parallel. You are looking for something that isn't there.

Comment: Oh, so parallel lines do exist only at specific illustrations of Desargues' finite geometry?

Comment: You will have to look up "Desargues' finite geometry" yourself. I can't find a reference to it other than the name of a computer geometry package that isn't clear on why it was so-named. I can see no sensible reason for calling "Desargues' theorem" such a thing, so presumably it refers to something else. These two pictures are for Desargues' theorem, not Desargues' finite geometry. Don't assume that everything using Desargues' name must be the same thing.